# Viewing the actual desktop on a remote computer

Tags: debian, remote-desktop, raspberry-pi

I'm running an raspberry pi with a display connected to the hdmi port. With a remote computer I want to view the actual graphic desktop (started with startx) of the pi which one can see on the display.

Is it something with export DISPLAY? But I have no idea about the correct parameters. I have a ssh connection via putty and a RDP connection. But the RDP desktop I see on the remote computer is different from the desktop of the hdmi display.

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried VNC yet?

Comment: X forwarding won't give you the actual desktop being displayed on the Pi's local framebuffer; for that you need VNC. (I'm not sure how you got RDP working, but that's going to give you a separate login session as well, rather than the console's X session.)

Comment: Some desktop systems have a VNC server built in, it just needs activated.  [KDE has one](http://www.kde.org/applications/system/krfb/), memory says Gnome has something similar.

Comment: Yes, VNC! I installed x11vnc - and it works great!